# Black screen when launching app on Android device

Tags: android, flashdevelop

I am using Flashdevelop 4.0.4 RTM for MS.NET 2.0( R2337 ).
I have installed all the appropriate drivers for the device ( I think ), Adobe AIR on the device, ran the .BAT file to create a certificate, so basically everything I needed to do in order to run the app on the device.
However, when I run it on the device, I get a black screen. It does function without any trouble on the Emulator, which makes me think it is a driver issue, but I have installed the right driver and launching does work ( it just doesn't show anything ) which makes me think it is something else. Does anyone have an idea of what this might be, or had a similar situation themselves?

P.S. I don't know if it is important to tell that the device does not hold an SD card.

Greet, GP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you running it in debug mode?

```
:target
goto android-debug
```

if so, i had exactly the same problem.
Publishing as android-test was fine, but whenever i wanted the debugger to work, I got stalled at the black screen (probably the app waiting for the debugger to connect)

Turned out i needed to specify the IP address of my PC in the SetupApplication.bat.

So, assuming your phone and your PC are on the same WIFI, open up SetupApplication.bat, scroll down and change

```
:: Debugging using a custom IP
set DEBUG_IP=
```

to

```
:: Debugging using a custom IP
set DEBUG_IP=192.168.1.5
```

for example. 192.168.1.5 is the IP of my PC.

Please bear in mind that if your router allocates IPs dynamically, this might not always work as the IP of your PC may change each time it connects to the router. To fix this, i suggest you give your PC a fixed IP (within the range of your network).

After that, the debugger should connect and traces display in the output tab.

:-)